# Css for the rounder corner at the bottom of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the image:

[image: Here is the image]

Can anyone please help me out with the css of the image? I have created the circle at the bottom but unable to make it rounded at the endpoint of semicircle.

```css
div{
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0, circle,transparent 20%, red 10%);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:80px"></div>
```

Comment: Consider using `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`?

Comment: I don't want the rounded corner for rectangle, at the endpoint of the semicircle. Please check image once. It will clarify you more. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Seems the image is white, and the background is transparent.. :(